# In Java, I am trying to validate input by checking for invalid input. Somehow it is not correctly returning an error

Tags: java, validation

First off, let me give you a small description of what I'm trying to do. For an assignment for college I have to recreate the game Mastermind in Java. So far everything's been going well, untill I came to a specific point in validating the user's input. I have an array of Strings called colorList, this list is filled with letters A to F (these are subtitutes for colors.)

When the user makes a guess, he enters a 4 letter code, for example ABCD. What I want to make sure is that every character in the guess is also contained in the colorList array to prevent users from guessing 'colors' that do not exist.

The code I'm using to validate this is as followed:

```
    boolean incorrectInput = true;
    while (incorrectInput) {
        boolean ooitgoed = false;
        outerloop: for (int a = 0; a < code.length(); a++) { // Select next letter in input.
            for (int i = 0; i < colorList.size(); i++) { // Select next element in array to compare to.
                ooitgoed = false; // Will put the boolean on false for as long as it does not find the selected char in the array.
                if (colorList.get(i).charAt(0) == code.charAt(a)) { // If selected input character is equal to selected element from array:
                    System.out.println("Code char: " + code.charAt(a) + " - " + "Element from array: " + colorList.get(i) + " - correct input");
                    ooitgoed = true;
                    incorrectInput = false;
                    break; // Break out of the for-loop, which causes the next character of the input to be selected and then compared to every element in the array.
                }
            }

            if (ooitgoed == false) { // If the selected char is never found in the array, the boolean will still be false and a new input will be requested.
                System.out.println("Found incorrect input! Please only use 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', or 'F'.");
                System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
                input = in.next();
                input = input.toUpperCase();
                incorrectInput = true;
                break outerloop; // Break back to outerloop, re-executing the entire validation process with the new input requested above. 
            }
        }
    }
```

I added some commentary to explain a couple of procedures during the code that SHOULD be working, and I'm not able to find why it's not working.

The output I get when I execute the program and take a guess is as followed:

> Code = DCFF
>
> Enter your guess:
> DCFU
>
> Code char: D - Element from array: D - correct input
>
> Code char: C - Element from array: C - correct input
>
> Code char: F - Element from array: F - correct input
>
> Code char: F - Element from array: F - correct input

The U should have been found as invalid input, but somehow the program thinks it's an F and proceeds to validate it as such.

I added some commentary to explain a couple of procedures during the code that SHOULD be working, and I'm not able to find why it's not working.

If you need more info regarding my code please let me know, I'll provide you with as much as I need. I hope anyone can figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show how you initialize the `code` and `colorList` variables?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a shorter way to do what you want:

```
private static final char[] COLORS = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};


public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String input;
    boolean inputOk;

    do {
        inputOk = true;

        // read the input
        System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
        input = br.readLine().toUpperCase();

        // do the check
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length() && inputOk; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLORS.length; j++) {
                if (input.charAt(i) == COLORS[j])
                    break;
                if (j == COLORS.length - 1)
                    inputOk = false;
            }
        }

        // input isn't ok
        if (!inputOk)
            System.out.println("Found incorrect input! Please only use 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', or 'F'.");
    } while (!inputOk);
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks, this seems to be working fine. The only thing that it doesn't to is that when the input returns as invalid, it should ask for new input and redo the entire validation process with the new input. How would you go about doing that? I currently put 

"System.out.println("Found incorrect input! Please only use 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', or 'F'.");
System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
input = in.next();
input = input.toUpperCase();"

 in the else statement but it would still need to redo the whole process.

Comment: Just edited in order to perform the request until the input is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! After a little bit of tweaking it worked out perfectly!

Comment: I used `BufferedReader` to read faster the user input. Perhaps you use another way. However, the core of the validation is the `do-while` loop. Another think you should check is the input length: `if (input.length() != 4)`.

Comment: I use a Scanner to read the input, and I already took care of the input.length() issue before all of this and I managed to get that to work just fine. Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are testing characters from `code` in your `incorrectInput` loop. Should be `input`.

Also a few comments about your code:

- You don't need both `ooitdoed` and `incorrectInput`, either one is enough to hold your condition.
- The `outerloop` is actually inner :) And you don't need that label - just `break`, without label will do.
- Do not write boolean checks like `if (ooitgoed == false)` - just `if(!ootitgoed)`
- You might find your implementation more clean and readable, if you make `colorList` a string "ABCDEF" instead of the array, and replace your innermost loop with `incorrectInput = colorList.indexOf(input.charAt(a)) == -1`
- You can also validate the whole string at once, without any procedural loops with a regular expression: `incorrectInput = !input.toUpperCase.matches("[A-F]+")`. Or, if you want to also report which character was wrong:

  ```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-F]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); // Do this before all loops
  // ...
  Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
  incorrectInput = m.find();
  if(incorrectInput) System.out.println("This symbol is invalid: " + m.group());
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I already got it figured out thanks to Giulio's answer but these are some tips that sure could be useful in the future. I'm still very much a beginner at programming and I'm in my first year of college so all tips are welcome :).

Comment: @PatrickNobbe Well, to be fair, I would not call  copying a pre-made complete solution to the problem "having figured it out" :) That approach is unlikely to help you with anything in the long run.

Comment: Having used his solution does not mean I didn't read through yours, I just figured his approach fit my situation better. It also helped me understand a new way of repeating loops namely using 'do', which I had never heard of before. I dont mean so say his solution is better, it just helped me more on short term. Your tips are helping me better in the long term and I agree, which is why I read through them all.

Comment: Nah, his "approach" is exactly the same as yours. What's "better" about it is that you can simply paste it into your file, and be done with the assignment instead of spending time fixing and cleaning up the (fairly good) work that you have come up with on your own. You can (*should*) read about "do/while" loops and other features of java syntax in your text book, it doesn't really matter all that much if you do/while or while/do in this case. The former lets you get away with declaring uninitialized variables, which is not a good thing to do to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's create a method to validate the `characters`. Let's call it `isCharValid`:

```
public boolean isCharValid(char ch, List<String> list) {
  for (String s : list) {
    if (s.charAt(0) == ch) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Now, change your code to:

```
while (true) {
  String input = in.next().toUpperCase();
  boolean validated = true;

  for (char ch : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (!isCharValid(ch, YOUR_COLOR_LIST)) {
      validated = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (validated) {
    // The input is OK!
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("Invalid output. Please, try again.");
    // Now it will go back to the beginning of the while-loop.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

General pointer: Make use of `List`s.

```
final List<Character> allowedInputs = new ArrayList<>();
allowedInputs.add('A');
allowedInputs.add('B');
allowedInputs.add('C');
allowedInputs.add('D');

final String input = getInput(); //gets the input from the user..

final char[] inputChars = input.toCharArray();

for (final char inputChar : inputChars) {
    if (allowedInputs.contains(inputChar)) {
        //All good
    } else {
       //Error in input!
}
```